# Connecting to Google Cloud SQL instance on private IP from a VM with both private and public IPs fails

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql, terraform-provider-gcp

## What I'm trying to set up:

- Cloud SQL instance with private IP, Postgresql database
- A VM with one public IP and one private IP on same VPC network as the SQL instance is on (VM, SQL instance and VPC are all in the same region)
- VM has a service account with sufficient Cloud SQL client/viewer permissions
- SQL proxy on VM connecting to SQL instance. I run it with the `-ip_address_types=PRIVATE` argument I've found in some of the documentation.

## Configuration code

Slightly simplified Terraform code for reproducing the state that confuses me is here:
https://github.com/hallvors/gcp-network-issue-demo
To test this, do the following:

1. create a new throwaway Google Cloud project.
2. For your convenience, you can run bootstrap.sh to enable the right services (it will ask for the ID of the Google project and assume you have a gcloud client which is logged in and has access).
3. Create a service account in the project, just make it owner for convenience, and save a key file in `./local-secrets/google-project-credentials.json`
4. Update terraform.tfvars with project ID and e-mail of service account
5. `terraform workspace new staging`
6. `terraform init`
7. `terraform apply`

When Terraform is done, you should have a database and a VM set up in the project.

1. SSH into the VM and run `sudo apt install postgresql-client-common postgresql-client`
2. Look up the IP address of the DB instance
3. Run this (modify details as needed) `psql --host 10.167.0.3 -U gcp-network-issue-demo-staging-db-user gcp-network-issue-demo-staging-database`

## What happens?

- Any attempt to actually use the connection, from for example psql client or db-migrate, times out
- If I remove the VM's public IP address from the setup, it connects fine. However, I need a publicly accessible VM for other services to connect to it..

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing details. 1) Show exactly how you are launching Cloud SQL Proxy. 2) Show exactly how you are connecting via `psql` etc. 3) What is `10.240.0.3`? 4) What roles are actually assigned to the service account?. 5) If Cloud SQL is addressed within the same VPC you do not need Cloud SQL Proxy, just directly connect to the private IP address with the correct PostgreSQL credentials.

Comment: Thank you for commenting! I will add the details :) I know I don't strictly need the SQL proxy (but direct connection times out the same way) - however there are some benefits to using it like using just an instance reference instead of configuring things with IP address.

Comment: 1) Verify that you can connect directly using the private IP address. 2) Did you authorize the networks that can connect? You might have overwritten the authorized networks blocking RFC1918 (private) addresses. Look at the command: `gcloud sql instances patch INSTANCE_NAME --authorized-networks`

Comment: Direct connection also fails 
`psql --host 10.240.0.3 -U postgres slipway-refactored-staging-database
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
 Is the server running on host "10.240.0.3" and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

You mean adding the public IP address of my VM as authorised? I tried to run 
` gcloud sql instances --project slipway-refactored  patch slipway-refactored-staging-database-instance --authorized-networks 35.228.181.106` but it did not seem to make a difference.

Comment: I have this in Terraform code:
`ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled    = false
      private_network = var.private_network
    }
`
and I was looking at adding authorized network details here at some point, but could not find a config that would make things work. Am I right you are suggesting to add the public IP of the VM as an "authorized" network?

Comment: You might need to authorize your RFC1918 address. Those are private IP addresses. The answer is in the details.

Comment: Now you mention Terraform. Start over and create a question with all the little details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221356/discussion-between-hallvors-and-john-hanley).

Comment: To assist you further, I may assist you with the underlying Google APIs that the Terraform Google Provider calls. Do you have examples?

Comment: Thanks for commenting @JohnHanley and MrTech - I have created a demo repository with just enough Terraform code to reproduce the state that confuses me. I have also simplified the question and removed stuff about SQL proxy since the connection issue can be reproduced easily.

Comment: Do you have a new question? From what I understand, you are having difficulty connecting from a Virtual Machine to a Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: Yes. Should I create a new question instead of tweaking this one? It is still the same issue I'm struggling with. Initially I thought describing the setup & config would suffice but John told me to post the Terraform code instead, so I've made a demo repository..

Comment: There is a lot going on. To me there is Terraform question and there is a connectivity question. A new question for connectivity will simplify things.

Comment: Please confirm that if you open the sql instance in the gui, go to connections, and add the host ip manually you connect from psql. I don't see in your terraform code that connection configured _inside_ the sql instance.

Comment: Hi @Iñigo, thanks but how would I add this IP? When the instance only has a private IP, the connections screen looks like this:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_xG4gBJM_WAvSgmTotPiMppbTBtFsReA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you already configured the private service access in your Cloud SQL instance? https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-private-ip#connecting_to_an_instance_using_its_private_ip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this problem was me failing to understand that a network interface can have *both* public and private IPs/networks. So my code set up one interface for the public and one for the private network for the google_compute_instance:

```
  # Update VM needs a public IP
  network_interface {
    network = "default"
    access_config {
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network    = var.network
    subnetwork = var.subnetwork
  }
```

Now, I still don't fully understand networking but it appears you can not (easily?) specify what interface the database connection attempts should use and it does not automatically pick the right one. The fix is in this commit, configuring both access to the private network and the public one in one network interface:

https://github.com/hallvors/gcp-network-issue-demo/commit/ea14174c1087c89b92310b5b4913e12a4e17130d