# Connecting to a Cloud SQL instance from VM with public and private IPs - how to ensure the right network interface is chosen for the connection?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

## What I'm trying to set up:

- Cloud SQL instance with private IP, Postgresql database
- A VM with a public IP, but also one private IP on same VPC network as the SQL instance is on (VM, SQL instance and VPC are all in the same region)
- VM has a service account with sufficient Cloud SQL client/viewer permissions
- Possibility to connect from VM to SQL instance.

## What happens?

- Any attempt to actually use the connection, from for example psql client or db-migrate, simply hangs - for example `psql --host 10.78.0.3 -U gcp-network-issue-demo-staging-db-user gcp-network-issue-demo-staging-database` will not prompt for a password, just sit there.
- If I remove the VM's public IP address from the setup, it connects fine. However, I need a publicly accessible VM for other services to connect to it..

I assume the psql connection attempt goes through the wrong network interface or something (this may be just my ignorance about network stuff speaking) - how can I get this working? What am I missing?

PS: this is basically same problem as [Connecting to Google Cloud SQL instance on private IP from a VM with both private and public IPs fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63853170/connecting-to-google-cloud-sql-instance-on-private-ip-from-a-vm-with-both-privat?noredirect=1#comment113205144_63853170) but commenters there seem to want one Terraform-related and one connection-issue-related question.

Some screenshots:

VM IPs:
[image: VM IP addresses]

DB IPs:
[image: DB IP addresses]

Network config for VM:
[image: VM networks]

Private IP config for DB instance:
[image: DB instance connections config]

This is the setup of the private network:
[image: VPC config screenshot]

I don't understand why the private IP of the DB instance (`10.78.0.3`) is not an IP from the range of the private network (`10.2.0.0`-`10.2.0.24`, right?)..? Is that my problem?

Comment: Is the Cloud SQL private IP address located in the same VPC as the Compute Engine instance? (Hint: It is not). If no, then you will need to use the Cloud SQL Proxy to connect. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-private-ip AND https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy

Comment: Can you share more about your environment? did you change the route configuration? to you have a NAT configured? Did you perform special stuff or it's a default project?

Comment: Please, and what is the IP range configured for the demo staging network? Why do you say that the private IP of the DB instance is not an IP from the range of the private network?

Comment: @JohnHanley is there a way to make sure the private IP of the Cloud SQL instance is from the private network? I sort of expected this to just happen when I tell the SQL instance to be "associated with" that private network but this assumption appears to be wrong..

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have added some screenshots of the config. It is all set up by Terraform code as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63853170/connecting-to-google-cloud-sql-instance-on-private-ip-from-a-vm-with-both-privat and I have not set up NAT or routes stuff. Maybe that's what I need to add?

Comment: @jccampanero I added one more screenshot.

Also, thank you all for commenting. With your help I might finally understand this some day :)

Comment: Does the "default" VPC network contain a subnet with a range that overlap the IP of your database?

Comment: I am happy to hear that you manage to solve the problem @hallvors. I'm sorry, I was digging into it but did not have enough time to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

> I don't understand why the private IP of the DB instance (10.78.0.3) is not an IP from the range of the private network (10.2.0.0-10.2.0.24, right?)..?

The Cloud SQL instance is assigned an IP address from the [allocated range](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-services-access#allocating_an_ip_address_range). When you setup a [private services access](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-services-access) a VPC peering is created between your VPC **gcp-network-issue-demo-staging-network** and **the service producer VPC network** that uses the allocated range 10.78.0.0/16
[image]

Also, looking at your VM network config, I see that the VM has two Nics in two different VPCs (**default** and **gcp-network-issue-demo-staging-network**). In your case, you can use only one Nic.

As a next step, make sure that your VM is using only the VPC network that you have used to create the [private connection](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-services-access#creating_a_private_connection). Once that done you should be able to connect to the Cloud SQL instance IP using the command bellow:

```
telnet 10.78.0.3 3306
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! Does this simply mean that what I'm trying to do (a VM connecting to DB over a private network but also having a public IP) is simply not supposed to be possible? Because if I follow the advice to "make sure that your VM is using only the VPC network that you have used to create the private connection" - the VM will no longer have a public IP, right?

Comment: A VM connecting to DB over a private network but also having a public IP can definitely work. I was able to set it up, but the VM I have created used only one NIC. My question is: 1- is there a particular reason why you have created the gcp-network-issue-demo-staging-network and why your VM is using 2 NICs? 
2- Have you used the gcp-network-issue-demo-staging-network to create the private service connection?
However, you can use only nic0 with private IP 10.166.0.2 and Public IP 35.228.223.46 if you have set up a private service connection with the 'default' subnet.

Comment: I thought this was the right way to do it (I suppose I know just enough about networking to be close to hopelessly confused..). I have now changed the setup to have one network interface, it references the VPC and also has an ephemeral public IP address. I think all it needs now is a firewall rule allowing SSH access and I'll have found the configuration I'm aiming for

Comment: Here is a good [tutorial](https://geekflare.com/gcp-firewall-configuration/) to help you with setting up ssh firewall rules on the compute engine VM.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I figured out how to fix my Terraform code in the corresponding question and self-answered that one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63853170/connecting-to-google-cloud-sql-instance-on-private-ip-from-a-vm-with-both-privat/64258666#64258666